# Bootstrap Carousel active class not working in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

For some reason the 'active' class for the carousel is not cycling for the following code:

```
<div id="foo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="overlay"><h1>SOME TEXT HERE</h1></div>
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#foo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#foo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#foo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" id="main-carousel"  role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <%= image_tag("someImage.JPG") %>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <%= image_tag("someImage.JPG") %>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <%= image_tag("someImage.JPG") %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

at the bottom of the page I have the following script tag:

```
<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 3000 });
</script>
```

The active class does not move to the second or third item.

Comment: try to check if there is no error in developer console.

Comment: That should work fine -- though because you're using data, you don't need to to initlalize in js. -- did you remember to add the bootstrap js require to your application.js ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code from everything I can tell here. The only problems I see could be with:

1. The path to your images is incorrect.
2. You do not have the dependencies for bootstraps carousel loaded into your project which require `bootstrap.css` `jQuery` and the `bootstrap.js` script.

Working fiddle with your exact code here: https://jsfiddle.net/khvgqkme/

Comment: Thanks very much for your response Maxwell. I do in fact have those dependencies loaded in my project as well as the correct path for the images. Perhaps I am overriding something in another part of the code. Thanks anyway!